# Flexslider move around elements

Tags: jquery, css, flexslider

I have a strange problem with the Jquery plugin Flexslider. When there is a change from one slide to the next (only in the mobile version, viewport <480) all other elements seem to shake. This problem started when I added to the page a script for the mobile responsive menu using Modernizr, but I would not know what the problem is. The test site is http://private2.portalesardegna.com

and this is the reference for the mobile menu script http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/15/off-canvas-navigation-for-responsive-website/

Comment: Can't replicate the problem on my Nexus 4 or by resizing my desktop browser. Seems nice and smooth on both.

Answer (score 0):

i think it's because there are 2 divs

```
<div id="outer-wrap">
<div id="inner-wrap">
```

that contains all the page elements, they are necessary for the mobile menu, but all the jquery scripts that move image (flexslider in home page and the image gallery in the hotels detail page) shake all the content, i tested the site in the iphone and with safari...

the css applied to those divs are

```
#outer-wrap {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

#inner-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: i solved using another script from http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/15/off-canvas-navigation-for-responsive-website/ the jquery script i slower but works fine